# Can't delete forum threads

Tags: forum

I'm trying to delete a forum thread using Forum Module v 3.1.10 and EE 2.5.2 and after I hit the delete confirmation button I get redirected to the site's home page which is blank. Refreshing the page brings up a dialogue for confirming form submission, and I get returned to the blank page.

If I manually change the URL in the address bar and then return to the forum, the thread is still there. So I'm unable to delete forum threads.

Turning on debugging in index.php isn't showing any errors.

Anyone else had this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using .htaccess to either add or remove a trailing slash from your site URLs? If a request gets rerouted in that manner it gets stripped of the POST data, so that might be one possibility.

On a site where I was **adding** a trailing slash (which I do not believe is the default behavior any more), I added a condition to the rewriterule (second line below) in `.htaccess` file to NOT redirect a request if it had POST data:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

That patched the forums up and I haven't noticed any side effects.

Comment: Yeah thought about that already and removed those rules with no change. Generally when that's been an issue with other forms though, the form submits back to itself but with no data saved; you don't get redirected to a different blank page.